# Save plot from pandas in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I am trying to save plots of a pandas' dataframe in a jupyter notebook, but I am getting a blank image of 72 Bytes size.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    EperDtDF = spark.sql("SELECT timestamp, data.ldr from deviceData where timestamp >= '2018-05-01T00:00:00+02:00' and timestamp < '2018-05-07T23:59:59+02:00'")
    EperDtDF.cache()
    EperDtPanda = EperDtDF.toPandas().set_index('timestamp')
    slice = EperDtPanda[0:4321].plot() # slice of first 6h (double of previous calculation)

    fig = slice.get_figure()
    fig.savefig('test2', format='png')
```

The file created is there, with the right name, but having just 72 Bytes, and I cannot open it, as it is a blank image.

How to save the plot which is displayed the right way?

Comment: Does this happen when producing a [mcve] as well?

Comment: You could try `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and instead of last two lines: `plt.savefig('test2.png')`

Comment: Adding `.png` to the filename manually will solve the problem. This is reproducible using a string as a filename without an extension and setting a `format`

Comment: none of above comments helped unfortunately :-/